# What is the Rust equivalent of Scala's value classes?

Tags: rust

[Scala's value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) provide a way to use the type system without allocating runtime objects (structs in case of Rust). I'm looking for an equivalent in Rust.

The use case I'd like to cover is passing around a string that represents a URI, by annotating relevant signatures with something like `Uri` instead of `String`, and, ideally, use this `Uri` when a `String` is expected. All this with minimal overhead.

An obvious solution would be to use structs with one field:

```
struct Uri { val: String }
```

This has the drawback of slightly awkward usage, not being acceptable where a `String` is expected, and I'm unsure of its overhead.

Is there something similar to Scala's value classes in Rust? Is there some other mechanism that facilitates this use case?

Comment: You could try a type alias, `type Uri = String`, but a type alias cannot be considered similar to Scala's value class.

Comment: @EvilTak Type alias can't be used to distinguish between Uri and String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the thing you are looking for is the "strong type system". In Rust it is represented with a tuple struct with one field (a *newtype*):

```
struct Uri(pub String);
```

This creates a strong type with the least overhead. I'd say this just creates a mark for the compiler that this type is `Uri` and nothing else. Since this is a strong type, you can't simply pass `String` to it and get a `String` from it, you must do a conversion manually.

[Simple example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=211e0d0484c866c30fbc5c10bbfbdc9a&version=stable) gives you a strong type on top of the `String`:

```
struct Uri(pub String);

fn takes_uri(uri: Uri) {
    println!("URI: {}", uri.0);
}

fn takes_string(uri: String) {
    println!("String: {}", uri);
}

fn main() {
    let uri = Uri("https://stackoverflow.com".to_owned());
    takes_uri(uri);
    // takes_string(uri); // This does not compile
}
```

The key thing with strong types is that you can not implicitly cast them so this requires the code writer to write explicit code.

Comment: Could you say more about the reasoning against implicit casting? I'm inclined to use `From` or `Into` traits for implicit conversion.

Comment: There's also a solution for "use this `Uri` when a `String` is expected" in certain cases that you should add.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis using `From` / `Into` would be *explicit* because you have to type in the code `.into` or `Uri::from` somewhere. This marks the conversion location explicitly (which I agree is a good thing).

Comment: @DominykasMostauski Most of the point of strong types is to have semantically different types without adding overhead to the internal representation. Implicit conversions kind of go against that; But then again it depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: FWIW, a struct with a single field has *no* runtime overhead compared to the wrapped struct.